Can you actually stack Explosive Runes?
This answer implies you can, albeit without stating the reason.  I'd guess "absence of rules to the contrary" is the rationale, but I may be overlooking something. The spell clearly says the creature takes 6d6 damage:

Target one touched object weighing no more than 10 lbs.
... You trace mystic runes upon a book, map, scroll, or similar object bearing written information. The explosive runes detonate when read, dealing 6d6 points of force damage.

... but is "it stacks" the default assumption here?

Explosive runes is sometimes overrated but still very good
A caster can't cast explosive runes spells so that multiple explosive runes effects are present on a lone book, map scroll, or similar object so that, when the lone-yet-thoroughly-runed object is read, all the explosive runes effects detonate simultaneously for an enormous combined explosion. Trying to employ the explosive runes spell this way runs afoul of the rules for Combining Magical Effects.
However, a creature can still tote dozens of books, maps, scrolls, and similar objects that have each been separately the subject of the explosive runes spell. And a creature can arrange those treated objects so that all of the objects will be affected by the area dispel function of a greater dispel magic spell. And then the creature can hope the dice are ice cold when the creature makes its dispel checks. Each failed dispel check against a treated object will yield a 10-ft.-radius explosion that deals 6d6 damage that has the force descriptor.
(Don't worry about automatically dispelling your own effects in Pathfinder with the area function of the greater dispel magic spell: unlike the normal dispel magic spell, the area dispel function of the greater dispel magic spell says, "You may choose to automatically succeed on dispel checks against any spell that you have cast" (emphasis mine), not that you must.)
(When arranging objects, be careful not to have any objects provide total cover to treated objects from the area function of the greater dispel magic effect! You can't set off a letter treated with explosive runes that's still in an envelope with the area function of a greater dispel magic spell, for instance, because the letter has total cover from the spell because of the envelope it's in.)
Because a scroll requires only "an area about 8-1/2 inches wide and 11 inches long… to hold one spell" (see here) and because the explosive runes spell costs only time, an industrious caster may be carrying a lot of objects that have been subject to an explosive runes effect and be able to place a great many of them in the 20-ft. burst that'll be engulfed by his greater dispel magic spell. (At least 25 per 5 ft. flat square!) If there's a difference, he'll want the explosive runes spells cast at his maximum caster level yet actually cast the greater dispel magic at the minimum caster level that he can (typically caster level 11) so as to fail as many caster level checks as possible for the biggest boom.
This is the strictest reading. Your DM may be more generous because—honestly—the spell is hilarious. For instance, in a 2019 Reddit thread here, a comment says that a "duffle bag full of explosive runes + greater dispel magic is a classic nuke" [sic]. Except the scrolls under the top layer have total cover from the greater dispel magic spell therefore they'll be unaffected (and mundanely destroyed) when the top layer explodes. Much like having a book with each page having an explosive runes effect, you still gotta spread out the pages somehow or else the effort's largely wasted. While that's not as funny, it's also not as game-breaking. Nonetheless, a GM might still allow a big bag of booms just because it's cool.
Similarly, the Web comic Order of the Stick (influenced by the creator's D&D 3E, inclusive, experience) allows its casters to place explosive runes effects on a container and a wall and elsewhere for comedic effect. A 2014 Giant in the Playground Forums thread here presents an array ways players can try to convince GMs that the explosive runes spell might function, too, many of them purely speculative and reliant on an extremely agreeable GM.
Good luck, and you may also want to read the many other ways those Giant in the Playground Forums folks try to tinker with the spell. Y'know, if you dare.

Note: I authored the answer the question references.
